# How to use the pg node package in angular

Tags: node.js, database, angular, postgresql, npm

## Situation

Hi, I'm quite new to Angular, I've been doing some projects following tutorials, which then lead me to try to start my own project to practice my Postgres and newly acquired Angular *"skills"*.

I am trying to do a webapp that connects to a postgres DB using the [node pg module](https://node-postgres.com/).

*(I know sequelize is a thing and it seems to work better than pg but AFAIK sequelize doesn't let you run pure postgres commands through it)* **Please correct me if I am wrong about this**

## The problem

This is where I get stuck, I am trying to follow the instructions from the docs but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

I have tried:

- `const { Client } = require('pg');`
- `import { Client } from 'pg';`
- Also tried importing it in the `.angular-cli.json` in the `scripts` array
- All of these fail with errors similar to this

  ```
   ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '[...]\node_modules\pg\lib'
   ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in '[...]\node_modules\pg\lib\native'
  ```

But nothing seems to work properly. Am I doing this completely wrong?

Also, pretty dumb question. I believe angular does everything on the client side, this is a HUGE security risk for DB access in prod. If that is true, is there a way to write server-side .ts services? or are services server-side?

Comment: Do not package server-side libraries with the client-side ones. pg module is strictly for the server-side only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your serverside code in node using compiled ts, but probably not with angular.

Comment: So I  would need to create a backend with node and then provide my own API endpoints?

Comment: That is my understanding, but personally, I build my API's with PHP.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources to figure out how to create those? I don't mind PHP but I would rather avoid it.